# How to implement Hough Circle in Java

Tags: java, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

i want to find a circular object(Iris of eye, i have used Haar Cascase with viola Jones algorithm). so i found that hough circle would be the correct way to do it. can anybody explain me how to implement Hough circle in Java or any other easy implementation to find iris with Java.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find an iris you should be straightforward about this. The part of the iris you are after is actually called a limbus. Also note that the contrast of the limbus is much lower than the one of the pupil so if image resolution permits pupil is a better target. Java is not a good option as programming language here since 1. It is slow while processing is intense; 2. Since classic Hough circle requires 3D accumulator and Java probably means using a cell phone the memory requirements will be tough.

What you can do is to use a fact that there is probably a single (or only a few) Limbuses in the image. First thing to do is to reduce the dimensionality of the problem from 3 to 2 by using oriented edges: extract horizontal and vertical edges that together represent edge orientation (they can be considered as horizontal and vertical components of edge vector). The simple idea is that the dominant intersection of edge vectors is the center of your limbus. To find the intersection you only need two oriented edges instead of three points that define a circle. Hence dimensionality reduction from 3 to 2.

You also don’t need to use a classical Hough circle transform with a huge accumulator and numerous calculations to find this intersection. A Randomized Hough will be much faster. Here is how it works (~ to RANSAC): you select a minimum number of oriented edges at random (in your case 2), find the intersection, then find all the edges that intersect at approximately the same location. These are inliers. You just iterate 10-30 times choosing a different random sample of 2 edges to settle in a set with maximum number of inliers. Hopefully, these inliers lie on the limbus. The median of inlier ray intersections will give you the center of the circle and the median distance to the inliers from the center is the radius.

In the picture below bright colors correspond to inliers and orientation is shown with little line segment. The set of original edges is shown in the middle (horizontal only). While original edges lie along an ellipse, Hough edges were transformed by an Affine transform to make those belonging to limbus to lie on a circle. Also note that edge orientations are pretty noisy.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[Duda and Hart (1971)](http://www.ai.sri.com/pubs/files/tn036-duda71.pdf) has a pretty clear explanation of the Hough transform and a worked example. It's not difficult to produce an implementation directly from that paper, so it's a good place for you to start.

Answer (score 2):

ImageJ provides a [Hough Circle plugin](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/hough-circles.html). I've been playing around with it several times in the past.
You could take a look at the source code if you want or need to modify it.